Classification of visible actions for *reducible* representations?

Is there a classification of the pairs $(G,V)$ such that $G$ is reductive [and connected, if you like], and $G$ acts faithfully and visibly on $V$ - crucially, including all cases where $V$ is reducible.

I'm hoping there's a reference that already does this, or there's something not too hard that I'm missing beyond my observations below.
(Dropping the assumption of connectedness seems not too bad: adding a finite group on top of $G$ can only combine finitely many orbits into one, and although it can reduce the number of invariants and thus increase the nullcone, I think it can only do so "finitely much." I haven't worked this out carefully but this is more motivation for my question than crucial to it.)
I'd also be interested in any progress towards this. For example, for each entry $(G,V)$ in the classification of irreducible visible spaces, what is the largest $k$ such that $(G,V^{\oplus k})$ is visible. Or classifying general (not just irreducible) visible spaces for certain families of groups, etc.
Background
Given a reductive algebraic group $G$ over the complex numbers, a regular action of $G$ on a complex vector space $V$ is visible if there are only finitely many orbits in the nullcone, or, equivalently, if $\pi:V \to V//G$ is the categorical quotient, then for every $[v] \in V//G$, the inverse image $\pi^{-1}([v])$ contains only finitely many orbits. (Visible actions are one definition that attempts to codify when the set of orbits of an algebraic action are "classifiable.")
The pairs $(G,V)$ for which $G$ is reductive and connected, $V$ is visible, and $G$ acts faithfully and irreducibly on $V$ have been classified in Kac - Some remarks on nilpotent orbits (with some corrections in Dadok–Kac - Polar representations). My question is:
Some observations
(1) Let $V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n V_i$, where $V_i$ are irreducible representations. The direct product of the nullcones of the $V_i$ is contained in the nullcone of $V$, so if $V$ is visible then so must be each $V_i$. However, $G$ need not act faithfully on each $V_i$, so long as it acts faithfully on them "jointly" (that is, if $\rho_i \colon G \to GL(V_i)$ is the corresponding representation, we only need that $\bigcap_i Ker(\rho_i) = 1$, but not necessarily that $Ker(\rho_i)=1$ for each $i$). So each pair $(G/Ker(\rho_i), V_i)$ must occur in the classification of irreducible visible spaces by Kac and Dadok-Kac mentioned above.
(2) Even if the nullcone of $V$ were equal to the direct product of the nullcones of the $V_i$, the $V_i$ being visible is not sufficient for $V$ being visible. The issue can be seen already for $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$. In this case, orbits in $V$ are not (usually) in bijection with pairs consisting of an orbit from $V_1$ and an orbit from $V_2$. Rather, for each orbit $\mathcal{O}$ in $V_1$, choose $x \in \mathcal{O}$ and let $H = Stab_G(x)$. Then orbits in $V$ that contain $x$ as their first coordinate correspond bijectively to the $H$-orbits in $V_2$, of which there could be many more (even infinitely many more) than $G$-orbits in $V_2$. An example of this is already furnished by $(G,V \oplus V)$, where $G=GL(V)$ in its defining action on $V$, and we let $G$ act on two copies of $V$. $(G,V)$ is visible, but $(G,V \oplus V)$ isn't (as you can see by looking at reduced row echelon form).
In fact, I don't know of any example of a visible pair $(G,V)$ such that $(G,V \oplus V)$ is still visible, but I've only checked a few examples. (Maybe it is easier for this to happen if $V$ only has finitely many orbits in total?)
(3) If $(G,V)$ and $(H,U)$ are visible, then $(G \times H, V \oplus U)$ is visible, where $G \times 1$ acts trivially on $U$, and $1 \times H$ acts trivially on $V$. In this case, using the characterization of the nullcone in terms of having 0 in the orbit closure, it is straightforward to show that the nullcone of $V \oplus U$ is just the direct product of the nullcones of $(G,V)$ and $(H,U)$. And because $G$ acts trivially on $U$ and $H$ acts trivially on $V$, the set of orbits in the nullcone of $V \oplus U$ is in bijection with pairs of orbits, one each from the nullcones of $V$ and $U$.
(4) We can also have more complicated actions. For example, suppose that $(G,V)$ and $(H,U)$ are both spaces with only finitely many orbits. We can define an action of $G\times H$ on $V \oplus U$ whereby $G$ acts as it originally did on $V$, and acts on $U$ by scaling by some nonzero power of the determinant, and analagously for the action of $H$. And it still has only finitely many orbits, so it is definitely still visible. Now the group is still a direct product, the space is still a direct sum, but the factors of the direct product can act nontrivially on all summands of the vector space.
And of course, we can surely (?) have more complicated groups, that combine more than one group from Kac's list, and in less trivial ways than the examples above. However, because the groups are reductive, they are fairly rigid (in terms of e.g. their subdirect products), so maybe they can't get too much more complicated when trying to combine them.
