Representations with finitely many nilpotent orbits
Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $G$. We can define the ``nilpotent cone'' of $V$ as
$$\mathcal{N}(V):=\{ v\in V\;: \; 0\in\overline{G\cdot v}\},$$
where we take the Zariski closure of the orbit. When $V = Lie(G)$, this is the classical nilpotent cone and there are finitely many orbits. More generally, when $\mathfrak{h} = \oplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}} \mathfrak{h}_i$ is a finitely graded Lie algebra such that $Lie(G) = \mathfrak{h}_0$, then each graded piece gives a representation with finitely many nilpotent orbits (when $n=2$ this is the classical setting of symmetric spaces, and in general I think these are called Vinberg $\theta$-representations).
My question is

For which representations $V$ does $\mathcal{N}(V)$ have finitely many orbits?

One can cook up silly things where there are infinitely many (take homothety action of $G=\mathbb{C}^\times$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$), but off the top of my head I don't know an example when $G$ is semi-simple.
A nice source of examples generalizing the symmetric pairs one is to suppose $G\subset G'$ is a spherical subgroup of a larger group and we consider the isotropy representation $$V= \{v\in Lie(G')^\ast : v|_{Lie(G)}\equiv 0\},$$
so that $T^\ast(G'/G) = G'\times^G V$. Is it known if $\mathcal{N}(V)$ has finitely many orbits?

You may want to look and NUMBER OF COMPONENTS OF THE NULLCONE by V. L. POPOV.

This is a sequence of remarks and a partial answer the question. I won't accept it at this point in case someone can say something more general/ intelligent.

Thanks to @Nandor for pointing out the paper by Popov, which has some statements in this direction. In particular, there is the following amazing result.

Theorem: Suppose that $G$ is a simple algebraic group acting irreducibly on $V$. Then following are equivalent:

the nilpotent cone $\mathcal{N}(V)$ has finitely many orbits,
Every fiber of the invariant quotient $\pi_V: V\to V//G$ has finitely many $G$-orbits (note $\mathcal{N}(V)= \pi_V^{-1}(\pi(0))$),
All fibers of $\pi_V$ have the same dimension,
the $G$-stabilizers of points in general position in $V$ are non-trivial,
The algebra of $G$-invariant polynomials $\mathbb{C}[V]^G$ is a polynomial algebra (so $V//G$ is affine space),
$\mathbb{C}[V]$ is a free $\mathbb{C}[V]^G$-module
There exists a linear subvariety $\mathfrak{a}\subset V$ (a so-called Cartan subspace) such that the "Weyl group" $W_{\mathfrak{a}}= N_{G}(\mathfrak{a})/Z_{G}(\mathfrak{a})$ is finite and the restriction induces an isomorphism $$\mathbb{C}[V]^G\to\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{a}]^{W_{\mathfrak{a}}},$$
Up to an affine shift, the linear subvariety above may be chosen to have trivial Weyl group (this generalizes a Weierstrass section).

All of these statements are familiar from the context of symmetric pairs and Vinberg $\theta$-representations, but I had never seen this general equivalence before. Popov claims that this equivalence fails if you drop $G$ simple or $V$ irreducible, but I can't access the references at the moment.

More generally, if we allow general reductive $G$ acting on $V$ irreducibly, the question was answered by Kac in Theorem 1 of "Some remarks on nilpotent orbits" (citation below). Many of these are already contained in the cases I mentioned of symmetric pairs and Vinberg $\theta$-representations, but there are some new ones such as $G_2(\mathbb{C})\times \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ acting on the tensor product of the two standard representations.

Both results rely on complicated case-by-case analyses and comparison of classification lists.

Finally, I realized that a simple case of an isotropy representation $\mathfrak{g}^\perp$ of a spherical subgroup $G\subset G'$ with infinitely nilpotent orbits is given by $G=GL_n(\mathbb{C})\subset G'=GL_n(\mathbb{C})\times GL_{n+1}(\mathbb{C})$ (the so-called "Rankin--Selberg variety").

Kac, V. G., Some remarks on nilpotent orbits, J. Algebra 64, 190-213 (1980). ZBL0431.17007.
Popov, V. L., Number of components of the nullcone, Proc. Steklov Inst. Math. 290, 84-90 (2015); translation from Tr. Mat. Inst. Steklova 290, 95-101 (2015). ZBL1333.14042.

Such a representation is often called visible (see Dadok–Kac and also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.04121 Lemma 4.1).  Irreducibly faithful visible reps have been classified by Kac and Dadok–Kac (over complex numbers). In the irreducible case, many notions agree (see also https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.04845v4). You may be also interested in a similar question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/473836/classification-of-visible-actions-for-reducible-representations.
